# Multiple jQuery Scripts in one HTML page Not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML code with 3 jQuery Scripts and they are not working together correctly 
can SomeOne Help me to solve this, please

I do to solve this problem as I don't have any experience in jQuery

and how can I fix this issue?

UPDATE It works now but one drop-down menu at a time how can I make them work together

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Availabe Restaurants:
<br>
Burgers:

  <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="Garage" /> Burger Garage</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="Burger" /> Hardee's</label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="test" checked="checked" value="Factory" /> Burger Factory & More</label>
    <br>
    <select ID="DropDownList2" Height="18px" Width="187px">
        <option Value="Factory_Style_1">Turbo Chicken</option>
        <option Value="Factory_Style_2">Twin Turbo Chicken</option>
        <option Value="Factory_Style_3">Garage Burger</option>
        <option Value="Burger_Style_1">Chicken Fille</option>
        <option Value="Burger_Style_2">Grilled Chicken Fillet</option>
        <option Value="Burger_Style_3">Jalapeno Chicken</option>
        <option Value="Garage_Style_1">Original Burger</option>
        <option Value="Garage_Style_2">Twin Turbo Chicken</option>
        <option Value="Garage_Style_3">Shuwa Burger</option>
    </select>
    <br>

Desserts:

    <label><input type="radio" name="test1"  checked="checked" value="Dip" /> Dip N Dip</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="test1" value="Camel" /> Camel Cookies</label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="test1" value="Ravenna" /> Ravenna Kunafa</label>
    <br>
    <select ID="DropDownList3" Height="18px" Width="187px">

        <option Value="Dip_Style_1">Brownies Crepe</option>
        <option Value="Dip_Style_2">Fettuccine Crepe</option>
        <option Value="Dip_Style_3">Cream Puff Pyramid</option>
        <option Value="Camel_Style_1">Brownie Fondant</option>
        <option Value="Camel_Style_2">Lotus Pancake</option>
        <option Value="Camel_Style_3">Camel Lava</option>
        <option Value="Ravenna_Style_1">Konafa With Chocolate</option>
        <option Value="Ravenna_Style_2">Konafa Mabrooma With Cheese</option>
        <option Value="Ravenna_Style_3">Konafa Mabrooma With Cream</option>
    </select>
    <br>
Beverages:
<option>Dr.Shake</option>
<option>Juice Lab</option>
<option>Aseer Time</option>
  <label><input type="radio" name="test2"  checked="checked" value="Dr" />Dr.Shake</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="test2" value="Juice" /> Juice Lab</label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="test2" value="Aseer" /> Aseer Time</label>
    <br>
    <select ID="DropDownList4" Height="18px" Width="187px">

        <option Value="Dr_Style_1">Pressure Milkshake</option>
        <option Value="Dr_Style_2">Thermometer Milkshake</option>
        <option Value="Dr_Style_3">Brain Recovery Milkshake</option>
        <option Value="Juice_Style_1">G Lab</option>
        <option Value="Juice_Style_2">Summer Vimto</option>
        <option Value="Juice_Style_3">Summer Bubble Gum</option>
        <option Value="Aseer_Style_1">Hormone Happiness</option>
        <option Value="Aseer_Style_2">The King</option>
        <option Value="Aseer_Style_3">Berry Smothey</option>
    </select>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(){
var options = $("#DropDownList2").html();
$('#DropDownList2 :not([value^="Fac"])').remove();
$('input:radio').change(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $("#DropDownList2").html(options);
    $('#DropDownList2 :not([value^="' + text.substr(0, 3) + '"])').remove();});
    })();

 (function(){   
var options = $("#DropDownList3").html();
$('#DropDownList3 :not([value^="Dip"])').remove();
$('input:radio').change(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $("#DropDownList3").html(options);
    $('#DropDownList3 :not([value^="' + text.substr(0, 3) + '"])').remove();});
    })();

 (function(){   
var options = $("#DropDownList4").html();
$('#DropDownList4 :not([value^="Dr"])').remove();
$('input:radio').change(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $("#DropDownList4").html(options);
    $('#DropDownList4 :not([value^="' + text.substr(0, 3) + '"])').remove();});
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is it's because you declare and define `options` multiple times, but what is the desired behavior?

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I want to create a menu for food in one HTML page and they are conflicting with each other

Comment: There is no reason to have 3 separate `script` elements. Combine all the code into a single one and place that just before the closing `body` element. Right now, you are importing JQuery twice. `$.noConflict()` is not relevant here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ok I will try that Thanks

Comment: @ScottMarcus can you edit this code please <https://jsfiddle.net/j38tazq7/> that didn't work

Comment: You're going to have to define what "didn't work" means. Do you get an error in your console? What is supposed to happen? Also, please don't post your code somewhere else and ask for edits. Just edit your question here with your updated code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ok sorry, it works now but I can't make them work together check my updated post

Comment: Again, you haven't explained what it IS supposed to do. Also, now that you've changed your code, edit the question - - you no longer have 3 scripts.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Updated

Comment: Please read what I'm saying. Telling us "it doesn't work" doesn't help us help you. Please clearly explain what it **should** do and what **it doesn't work** means to you. Additionally, your question still says that you have 3 scripts, but you don't anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common global variable conflict issue. You can (must) wrap them all to self-executing function, which will keep all declared variables inside its own.

(conflict):

```js
var test = $('#btn-1').text();
$('#btn-1').on('click', function(){ console.log( test ); });

var test = $('#btn-2').text();
$('#btn-2').on('click', function(){ console.log( test ); });

var test = $('#btn-3').text();
$('#btn-3').on('click', function(){ console.log( test ); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-1">111</button>
<button id="btn-2">222</button>
<button id="btn-3">333</button>
```

(no conflict):

```js
(function(){
  var test = $('#btn-1').text();
  $('#btn-1').on('click', function(){ console.log( test ); });
})();

(function(){
  var test = $('#btn-2').text();
  $('#btn-2').on('click', function(){ console.log( test ); });
})();

(function(){
  var test = $('#btn-3').text();
  $('#btn-3').on('click', function(){ console.log( test ); });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-1">111</button>
<button id="btn-2">222</button>
<button id="btn-3">333</button>
```

But in your case, at least would be better to run everything in loop (or adding a general class for all elements and loop with `$('.class').each(function(){/*...*/})`):

```
for( var i = 2; i < 5; i++ ){
  doStuff( i );
}

function doStuff( index ){
  var options = $("#DropDownList" + index).html();
  $('#DropDownList' + index + ' :not([value^="Dr"])').remove();
  $('input:radio').change(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $("#DropDownList" + index).html(options);
    $('#DropDownList' + index + ' :not([value^="' + text.substr(0, 3) + '"])').remove();
  });
}
```

Here was used the function as well, to "keep" variables inside.

Comment: I really would like to thank you for the explanation it worked

Comment: UPDATE it works but only one at a time :(  https://jsfiddle.net/j38tazq7/2/

Comment: Whenever you find yourself with largely the same code in more than one place, you should stop and think about how you can write the code just once. The way you do that is to figure out what's different between the repeated code and extract that out of the code (could be an argument that gets passed in, could be a variable that gets used). In your button examples above, all you need is this single line of JavaScript: `$('button').on('click', function(){ console.log(this.id); });`. No repeated code, no IIFEs.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have 3 functions that largely do the same thing and they all share the same variable. Instead of 3 functions that work on one element each, make one function that works on all 3 elements.

Note that no `id`s are needed here, just classes to organize the sets of radio buttons with the matching `option` elements.

See the comments inline:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Order Selection</title>
  <style>
    /* Do all your styling in CSS not inline with the HTML */
    select { width:187px; display:block; margin:10px; }
    .hidden { display:none; }
    fieldset { margin-top:1em; margin-bottom:1em; }
    legend { font-weight:bold; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Availabe Restaurants:</h1>
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Burgers:</legend>

    <label><input type="radio" name="burgers" value="Garage"> Burger Garage</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="burgers" value="Burger"> Hardee's</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="burgers" value="Factory"> Burger Factory &amp; More</label>

    <select name="burgers">
      <option value="">--- Select Burger ---</option>    
      <option class="Garage" value="Garage_Style_1">Original Burger</option>
      <option class="Garage" value="Garage_Style_2">Twin Turbo Chicken</option>
      <option class="Garage" value="Garage_Style_3">Shuwa Burger</option>
      <option class="Burger" value="Burger_Style_1">Chicken Fille</option>
      <option class="Burger" value="Burger_Style_2">Grilled Chicken Fillet</option>
      <option class="Burger" value="Burger_Style_3">Jalapeno Chicken</option>
      <option class="Factory" value="Factory_Style_1">Turbo Chicken</option>
      <option class="Factory" value="Factory_Style_2">Twin Turbo Chicken</option>
      <option class="Factory" value="Factory_Style_3">Garage Burger</option>        
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Beverages:</legend>

    <label><input type="radio" name="beverages" value="Dr" />Dr.Shake</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="beverages" value="Juice"> Juice Lab</label>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="beverages" value="Aseer"> Aseer Time</label>

    <select name="beverages">
      <option value="">--- Select Beverage ---</option>       
      <option class="Dr" value="Dr_Style_1">Pressure Milkshake</option>
      <option class="Dr" value="Dr_Style_2">Thermometer Milkshake</option>
      <option class="Dr" value="Dr_Style_3">Brain Recovery Milkshake</option>
      <option class="Juice" value="Juice_Style_1">G Lab</option>
      <option class="Juice" value="Juice_Style_2">Summer Vimto</option>
      <option class="Juice" value="Juice_Style_3">Summer Bubble Gum</option>
      <option class="Aseer" value="Aseer_Style_1">Hormone Happiness</option>
      <option class="Aseer" value="Aseer_Style_2">The King</option>
      <option class="Aseer" value="Aseer_Style_3">Berry Smothey</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
    
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Desserts:</legend>

    <label><input type="radio" name="desserts" value="Dip"> Dip N Dip</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="desserts" value="Camel"> Camel Cookies</label>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="desserts" value="Ravenna"> Ravenna Kunafa</label>

    <select name="desserts">
      <option value="">--- Select Dessert ---</option>       
      <option class="Dip" value="Dip_Style_1">Brownies Crepe</option>
      <option class="Dip" value="Dip_Style_2">Fettuccine Crepe</option>
      <option class="Dip" value="Dip_Style_3">Cream Puff Pyramid</option>
      <option class="Camel" value="Camel_Style_1">Brownie Fondant</option>
      <option class="Camel" value="Camel_Style_2">Lotus Pancake</option>
      <option class="Camel" value="Camel_Style_3">Camel Lava</option>
      <option class="Ravenna" value="Ravenna_Style_1">Konafa With Chocolate</option>
      <option class="Ravenna" value="Ravenna_Style_2">Konafa Mabrooma With Cheese</option>
      <option class="Ravenna" value="Ravenna_Style_3">Konafa Mabrooma With Cream</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Hide the dropdown lists until a radio button selection is made
    $("select").hide();

    // Set up a change event handler for each of the radio buttons
    $('input:radio').on("change", updateChoices);

    function updateChoices(e) {
      // Show the appropriate list based on the name of the radio button that was changed
      $('select[name="' + this.name  + '"]').show();
      
      // Reset any previously selected option in the list back to the default
      $('select[name="' + this.name  + '"]').val($('select[name="' + this.name  + '"] option:first').val());
  
      // Update the <option> elements in the corresponding <select>
      $('select[name="' + this.name  + '"] option').each(function(index,element){
      
        // If the option has the same class as the radio button that was changed...
        if($(element).hasClass(e.target.value)){
          $(element).show();  // Show the option
        } else {
          $(element).hide();  // Hide the option
        }
      });  
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```